# How to parse one group out of the two groups of command line arguments using argparse in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I want to develop a CLI that takes one of the two pairs of arguments together:

```
group-resources --limit 5
```

or

```
group-overlap --groups group1,group2
```

The group-resources is positional and limit is required. Same rules are for the rest of the two.
However, my current code makes it a compulsion that all four are required.

My current code:

```
import argparse

import analysis
import cleanup
import etl
import initialize_db

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Inventory DB for Cloud Infrastructure')
parser.add_argument(
    'group-resources', help='List top k groups as per their memory, disk, and cpu count.')
parser.add_argument(
    '--limit', help='Number of groups in descending order of their resources.', type=int, required=True)
parser.add_argument(
    'group-overlap', help='Fetch nodes that belong in both the groups')
parser.add_argument(
    '--groups', help='specify the group names separated by a comma.', type=str, required=True
)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

When I run `python3 cli.py group-resources --limit 5`, I get the following error:

```
usage: cli.py [-h] --limit LIMIT --groups GROUPS group-resources group-overlap
cli.py: error: the following arguments are required: group-overlap, --groups
```

I want that if I provide group-resources and limit, or if I provide group-overlap and groups, then my code should work. No other permutation should be allowed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers). Here is how we can do with slight modification in your code.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Inventory DB for Cloud Infrastructure')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='types of arguments')

group_resources_parser = subparsers.add_parser("group-resources", help='List top k groups as per their memory, disk, and cpu count.')
group_overlap_parser = subparsers.add_parser("group-overlap", help='Fetch nodes that belong in both the groups')
group_resources_parser.add_argument(
    '--limit', help='Number of groups in descending order of their resources.', type=int, required=True)
group_overlap_parser.add_argument(
    '--groups', help='specify the group names separated by a comma.', type=str, required=True
)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

**Examples:**

1. python3 cli.py group-resources

   ```
     usage: cli.py group-resources [-h] --limit LIMIT
     cli.py group-resources: error: the following arguments are required: --limit
   ```
2. python3 cli.py group-overlap

   ```
    usage: cli.py group-overlap [-h] --groups GROUPS
    cli.py group-overlap: error: the following arguments are required: --groups
   ```
3. python3 cli.py group-resources --limit 5 group-overlap

   ```
     usage: cli.py [-h] {group-resources,group-overlap} ...
     cli.py: error: unrecognized arguments: group-overlap
   ```